# Jquery mobile remove formatting on image

Tags: jquery, image, mobile, hyperlink

I'm using Jquery mobile and have an image at the top of my site designed to link to the home page.

However setting a link on this image causes Jquery mobile to format the image into a button.

I've had a look around but can't find a way to stop this.... anyone got any ideas?

Example with link: http://jsfiddle.net/wDYt6/

Example without link: http://jsfiddle.net/ewn7T/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a height to your header data-role div and remove the BR.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" style="background-color:#414141; background-image:none;height:80px">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif" width="100%" id="headerImage"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you add a link around an image Jquery mobile adds a few classes(ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-a) to that anchor tag.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to remove all classes on pageload using jquery mobile?

Comment: I don't know if you necessarily want to do that. I think adding the height fixes your issue. Have you look at [jQuery mobile Docs - Header Bars](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html#/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html)?

Comment: I'm looking to have the image at the top of the page displayed as it would be without jQuery Mobile, no extra borders or padding... just an image

Comment: I see in that case from the data-role="header from the div and use it just as a div tag then no jQuery mobile specific code will be added.

Comment: Perfect! that simple... hmmm.

Answer (score 6):

Found a better answer here: [How can i stop jQuery mobile to apply styles to my specific form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108578/how-can-i-stop-jquery-mobile-to-apply-styles-to-my-specific-form-elements)

jQuery Mobile will ignore elements whose data-role attributes are set to none. Therefore, you can simply add these attributes to your markup:

```
<a href="/" data-role="none"><img src=""></a>
```

Comment: this is totally the answer.  data-role="none" removes all the jquery markups on the <a href> but allows you to still use the data-role="header" on the div.  thanks andybak.

Comment: It still added some tags for me. I had to add class="none" to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

I use `data-role="none"` which worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `data-role="header"` with something else.