# How can i stop jQuery mobile to apply styles to my specific form elements

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to instruct jQuery Mobile to not style my Input box and submit button. I am good with my custom CSS. jQuery mobile script is applying its own style to all my elements.

the one workaround i tried is overriding those elements in my custom css. Is there any other functions available where i can do this ? some thing like this

```
$.ignoreStyles("button,text");
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

jQuery Mobile will ignore elements whose `data-role` attributes are set to `none`. Therefore, you can simply add these attributes to your markup:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" data-role="none" />
<button type="button" id="bar" data-role="none">Button</button>
```

Comment: Works very well for those exceptions where you need avoid jquery mobile styling on a certain pages and certain elements.

Comment: Is a submit button with data-role="none" still gooing to work?

Answer (score 7):

This works for me.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
});

<div data-enhance="false">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" id="chkbox1" 
      checked />
    <label for="chkbox1">Checkbox</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radiobtn1" id="radiobtn1" 
      checked />
    <label for="radiobtn1">Radio Button</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

@angelokh solution worked for me. Also look at the following link:

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781849517225/7dot-configurations/ch07s06_html

Also the key is to **add the following script before including jquery.mobile.js:**

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
});
```

Comment: the given link has solution but your answer here is not complete... anyway thanx

Comment: but then what's the purpose of using jquery mobile then?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', function( e ) {
    $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;
});
```