# How do I stop jQuery mobile from theming an ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, themes

We have an MVC site that has custom formatting throughout. We are using jQuery Mobile and want to use the features in it, but it themes everything. We do not want this.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108578/how-can-i-stop-jquery-mobile-to-apply-styles-to-my-specific-form-elements) and I added this Javascript code in the _Layout.cshtml page:

```
$(function () {
    $('html').find('*').attr('data-role', 'none');
});
```

This works for all of the elements, but sometime after the page loads jQuery inserts a `<div>` with the attribute `data-role="page"` which still causes issues.

Can I somehow disable themes altogether?

Comment: One of the main reasons to use jQuery Mobile is because it has themes. I don't think you can disable them. You can create your own themes, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple add `data-ajax=false` to the links/buttons who are responsible for the navigation.

Ex:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "MyPage")" data-ajax="false">
```

This will prevent jquery from use ajax for the transitions, you page will reload and the duplicated data-role=page will not be on DOM anymore.

It works for me, maybe can help you too.