# Only one input element with jQuery mobile, leave the rest untouched

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I can't figure out how I can register only one input-element in a page with jQuery mobile, where the rest should stay untouched by this framework... I've got an old slider, which doesn't work at all on mobile devices, that's why I thought I'll give jQuery mobile a shot. If I include the full library, the framework of course tries to change the whole page into a mobile-friendly page, which is not the goal. So I used the [Download Builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) where I left the 'Init' - component away. How would I need to register a single input element with jQuery mobile imperative?

My Html:

```
<!-- Lots of html... -->
<div style="max-height: 90px; min-height: 88px;" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="MySlider">Input slider:</label>
            <input type="range" name="MySlider" id="MySlider" value="60" min="0" max="100" step="10" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Lots of html... -->
```

P.s.: There is `data-role="none"` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108578/how-can-i-stop-jquery-mobile-to-apply-styles-to-my-specific-form-elements)). But in my case, it should be the other way round...

Comment: Have you tried calling $('#MySlider').slider();? I think it's far too much overhead to user JQM to enhance a single element in your page though.

Comment: how about wrapping your single element inside an iframe and loading JQM only in the iframe. Check any page of the [jqm api](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/) on how that is done. Should work

Comment: @frequent: Yeah, saw the solution with iFrame, but I don't like it much for my needs...

Comment: @AaronSpringer: Was also thinking the same, maybe it's simply the wrong solution for my needs. Do you know any good solution in order to get a mobile-friendly slider by any chance? P.s.: I need a simple slider, nothing which pictures/galleries.

Comment: @sl3dg3: I'm using [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/), which you can use without images aswell.

Comment: @frequent: You mean something like http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/sliders/ should be possible? Couldn't find any demo for that with Flexslider....

Comment: @sl3dg3: wait. Are you looking for a rangeslider as per your link or for a carousel with contents (slider-gallery)?

Comment: @frequent: Yes, that would be a rangeslider then... sorry for my imprecise naming.